# How to mount USB as user on FreeBSD?

Tags: permissions, mount, freebsd

How does one configure FreeBSD (with no GUI) to allow a non-root user to mount a USB drive?

I've followed the steps [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-allow-ordinary-users-mount-cd-rom-dvds-usb-removabledevice/), but I still get:

```
$ mount -t msdosfs -o shortnames /dev/da0s1 ~/media/d300
mount_msdosfs: /dev/da0s1: Operation not permitted
```

My configuration seems to be correct?

```
$ tail -n 2 /etc/devfs.conf
own     /dev/da0        root:vfs
perm    /dev/da0        0660
$ sysctl vfs.usermount
vfs.usermount: 1
$ id
uid=1000(matthew) gid=1000(matthew) groups=1000(matthew),900(vfs)
```

...but it doesn't seem to be taking effect:

```
$ ll /dev/da*
crw-r----- 1 root operator 0, 111 Jan  7 19:42 /dev/da0
crw-r----- 1 root operator 0, 112 Jan  7 19:42 /dev/da0s1
```

...and as Richard Smith pointed out to me, this apparently isn't expected to work for hot-pluggable devices anyway. So, how does one allow the user to mount hot-pluggable devices?

Comment: You may get a better response on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the mode of `/dev/da0s1`? (`ls -dl /dev/da0s1`). What user are you logged in as?

Comment: Ignoring the obvious `/dev/da00` typo, from [devfs.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devfs.conf) it states "It does not work for devices plugged in and out after the system is up and running, e.g. USB devices.".

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, I showed the output of `id`. (What's the difference between unix.SE, superuser, and serverfaut anyway? There seems to be considerable overlap...)

Comment: @RichardSmith, well, that explains why it doesn't work. How *does* one handle hot-pluggable devices, then? (As for the typo, yeah, I'd already fixed that, must have copy-pasted the pre-fix version. I'll edit that in the question.)

Comment: I haven't tried this, but have you seen the *Example* section in [devfs.rules(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devfs.rules&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE+and+Ports)? It seems to be what you're looking for.